# Three point formula exercise question

Tags: numerical-methods

Using the table in the figure and the three point formula  find the approximate values of the derivative required f'(1.2).Also calculate Ea and Ev ( Actual error and error bound)
[image]

We notice that h=0.1

so f'(1.2)=[1/(2*0.1)]* [f(1.3)-f(1.1)] 
Is this correct?

How to find Ea and Ev now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will map it out and you can fill in the details.

To find the derivative, we use:

$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h} - \frac{h^2}{6} f^{(3)}(\xi_0)$$

where $\xi_0 \in (x-h, x+h)$.

For your problem:

$$\tag 1 f'(1.2) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h} = \frac{f(1.3) - f(1.1)}{2 \times 0.1}$$

The error bound will be given by:

$$\mbox{Max}~ \left|- \frac{h^2}{6} f^{(3)}(\xi_0)\right|, \xi_0 \in (x-h, x+h)$$

The actual error will be given by:

$$|\mbox{Actual value} - \mbox{Calculated value from}~(1)|$$

Comment: Actual error is Ev right?

Comment: I will solve this and post the answers to compare them with yours

Comment: So f'(1.2) is 22.19365, Error bound is 0.17951650713

Comment: What is an actual value?

Comment: For the actual value, take the derivative of the known $f(x) = e^{2x}$ and evaluate it at $x = 1.2$, correct on error bound, correct on numerical derivative calculation.

Comment: Actual error =Ev= |-0.147|

Comment: That is correct.